# Using MySQL Count() with multiple conditions in different table

Tags: mysql, database, join, where-clause

I have following tables.

User_Location TABLE

```
  User_id|location_id
  _______|____________
     1   |     3        
     2   |     2    
     3   |     1
     4   |     1
```

User_Hobby TABLE

```
  User_id|  Hobby_id
  _______|____________
     1   |     1        
     1   |     3      
     1   |     5
     1   |     7        
     1   |     9      
     2   |     2
     2   |     4        
     2   |     6      
     2   |     8
     2   |     10        
     3   |     1     
     3   |     2
     3   |     3        
     3   |     4      
     3   |     5
     4   |     2     
     4   |     4
     4   |     6        
     4   |     8      
     4   |     10
```

Each user has five hobbies and one location. I want to count the number of same hobbies. For example, If my hobby list is **[1,2,3,4,5]** and Location_id is **1**, I need results like this.

```
  User_id|matched_hobby
  _______|____________
     3   |     5         ->[1,2,3,4,5] matched
     4   |     2         ->[2,4] matched
```

Any Idea about implementation?

********************* **UPDATE** *********************

Alex Martelli's answer works perfectly when there is only one location_id. What if there is a range of location_id in Tabel?
ex)

```
  User_id|location_id
  _______|____________
     1   |     3        
     2   |     2      
     3   |     10
     3   |     11
     3   |     12
     4   |     50
     4   |     51
     4   |     52
```

SELECT uh.User_id, COUNT(uh.Hobby_id)

FROM User_Location ul JOIN User_Hobby uh USING (User_id)

WHERE (ul.Location_id >= 5 AND ul.Location_id <= 15)

AND uh.Hobby_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

GROUP BY (uh.User_id)

is not working. It returns [#matched_hobby]*[#location_id]

It shoud be

```
  User_id|matched_hobby
  _______|____________
     3   |     5         ->[1,2,3,4,5] matched
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like

```
SELECT uh.User_id, COUNT(uh.Hobby_id)
   FROM User_Location ul JOIN User_Hobby uh USING (User_id)
   WHERE ul.Location_id = 1
     AND uh.Hobby_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
     GROUP BY (uh.User_id)
```

should give the results you're looking for.

Comment: What if the value of Location_id has range like (ul.Location_id>=1 AND ul.Location_id<=300)?
SELECT uh.User_id, COUNT(uh.Hobby_id)
   FROM User_Location ul JOIN User_Hobby uh USING (User_id)
   WHERE (ul.Location_id >= 1 AND ul.Location_id <= 300)
     AND uh.Hobby_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
     GROUP BY (uh.User_id) 
is not working.... : (

Comment: Can you check the UPDATE?

Comment: @KimCrab, it's really bad stackoverflow etiquette, once your original Q is answered, to edit the Q to add a further, different one. Proper etiquette is to keep to "one question per question", accept the best answer, and open a different question for the further, different problem you want to solve.

Comment: My bad. Sorry I didn't know that. I will not do that again.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT uh.User_id, COUNT(uh.Hobby_id)
FROM User_Location ul 
INNER JOIN User_Hobby uh ON ul.User_id = uh.User_id
WHERE uh.Hobby_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
AND (ul.Location_id >= 5 AND ul.Location_id <= 15)
GROUP BY uh.User_id, ul.Location_id
```

Comment: Where is WHERE claus for Location?

Comment: Gaikawd  Thanks for fast reply, but above QUERY has two WHERE claus which returns ERROR. So, I changed query like this. 

SELECT uh.User_id, COUNT(uh.Hobby_id)
FROM User_Location ul 
INNER JOIN User_Hobby uh ON ul.User_id = uh.User_id
WHERE uh.Hobby_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
AND WHERE (ul.Location_id >= 5 AND ul.Location_id <= 15)
GROUP BY uh.User_id, ul.Location_id

which returns  USER_id triple time! : (

Comment: How can I remove duplicate vaule?? your query returns  row1: user_id = 3   matched_hobby =  5   row2: user_id = 3   matched_hobby =  5  row3: user_id = 3   matched_hobby =  5

Comment: @KimCrab select location_id as well, i think all 3 rows will have different location_id

Comment: Ok I will try it! Thank you!